# Set Custom Start lines for Blazor Monaco

Tags: blazor, monaco-editor

How do I set the start line for my code editor using Blazor Monaco?

```
protected StandaloneEditorConstructionOptions SnippetEditorOptions(StandaloneCodeEditor editor)
    {
        editor.SetScrollPosition(new NewScrollPosition
        {
            ScrollLeft = 0,
            ScrollTop = 0,
        });       
        
        return new StandaloneEditorConstructionOptions
        {
            Language = "csharp",
            GlyphMargin = true,
            Value = Snippet,
            Minimap = new EditorMinimapOptions
            {
                Enabled = false,
            },                
           
        };
    }
```

How can i configure so that the code snippet will show line 10, for example, and not 1?